# Selenium 'Modal dialog present' but is not actually on screen

Tags: python, selenium

I have a comprehensive list of Australian postcodes, and I need to use the search function of a specific site to get corresponding remoteness codes. I created a Python script to do that, and it does it efficiently.

Except that, at a seemingly random time during the iteration, it throws a 'Modal dialog present' exception. The problem is, I see no dialog! The webpage looks as usual, and I can interact normally with it with my mouse. What could be the problem and is there a solution?

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox
browser.set_page_load_timeout(30)
browser.get("http://www.doctorconnect.gov.au/internet/otd/Publishing.nsf/Content/locator") # Load page
assert "Locator" in browser.title
search = browser.find_element_by_name("Search") # Find the query box
ret = browser.find_element_by_id("searchButton")

doha_addr = []
doha_ra = []

for i in search_string_list:
    search.send_keys(i)
    ret.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    addr = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
    doha_addr.append(addr.text)
    ra = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
    doha_ra.append(ra.text)
    try:
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div/div[13]/div[1]").click()
    except:
        pass
    search.clear()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have caught a glimpse of a popup dialog that shows up and hides itself while my script was running. Anyway, this becomes irrelevant with a while switch and a try/except clause... :7D

```
doha_ra = {}

for i in search_string_list:
    switch = True
    while switch == True:
        search.send_keys(i)
        ret.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        try:
            addr = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]")
            ra = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]")
            doha_ra[addr.text] = ra.text
            switch = False
        except:
            pass
        search.clear()
```